# Sorting a Data Table

Tags: .net, vb.net

I tried to sort a data table with following two ways

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "Town ASC, Cutomer ASC"

table.Select("", "Town ASC, Cutomer ASC")
```

But none of them wasn't worked. It always displays data in original order. Do you have any idea to solve the problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After setting the sort expression on the DefaultView (`table.DefaultView.Sort = "Town ASC, Cutomer ASC"` ) you should loop over the table using the DefaultView not the DataTable instance itself

```
foreach(DataRowView r in table.DefaultView)
{
    //... here you get the rows in sorted order
    Console.WriteLine(r["Town"].ToString());
}
```

Using the Select method of the DataTable instead, produces an array of DataRow. This array is sorted as from your request, not the DataTable

```
DataRow[] rowList = table.Select("", "Town ASC, Cutomer ASC");
foreach(DataRow r in rowList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r["Town"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 61):

This was the shortest way I could find to sort a DataTable without having to create any new variables.

```
DataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "ColumnName ASC"
DataTable = DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable
```

Where:

ASC - Ascending

DESC - Descending

ColumnName - The column you want to sort by

DataTable - The table you want to sort

Comment: Best solution for me right here. Works fast, I've actually incorporated this to ease database queries and perform sorting client-side. To add, sort multiple columns separated by a comma, i.e.: "Col1 ASC,Col2 DESC,Col3 ASC"

Comment: You forgot DataTable.AcceptChanges() after sorting.

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

```
Dim dataView As New DataView(table)
dataView.Sort = " AutoID DESC, Name DESC"
Dim dataTable AS DataTable = dataView.ToTable()
```

Comment: Good, but you should advise that this method creates a duplicated datatable, and if the original one is big this is not very efficient

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Town ASC, Cutomer ASC";
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void SortDataTable(DataTable dt, string sort)
{
DataTable newDT = dt.Clone();
int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;

DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select(null, sort);
// Sort with Column name
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
object[] arr = new object[dt.Columns.Count];
for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
{
arr[j] = foundRows[i][j];
}
DataRow data_row = newDT.NewRow();
data_row.ItemArray = arr;
newDT.Rows.Add(data_row);
}

//clear the incoming dt
dt.Rows.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < newDT.Rows.Count; i++)
{
object[] arr = new object[dt.Columns.Count];
for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
{
arr[j] = newDT.Rows[i][j];
}

DataRow data_row = dt.NewRow();
data_row.ItemArray = arr;
dt.Rows.Add(data_row);
}
}
```