# Sending a parameter to a stored procedure and using IF ELSE to order by field-asc-desc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I'm getting familiar with how stored procedures work on MSSQL 2012.

I have a table called Users:

```
Users
------
UserId
FirstName
LastName
CardNumber
```

I want a stored procedure where I give it what field to order by, and if it's asc or desc order.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users
if @filtername == "FirstName" && @filterorder == "DESC"
  ORDER BY FirstName DESC
else 
  ORDER BY FirstName ASC
```

How can I create a simple IF ELSE conditional in my SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not really addressing your question but best way would be to use the presentation layer to do this. Whether it be in the application ([see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472913/sorting-a-data-table)) or reporting services etc.

But if you have to do it from a stored procedure, you can either use dynamic sql (I prefer to avoid this when possible) or...

```
IF @filtername == "FirstName" && @filterorder == "DESC"
  SELECT UserId, FirstName, LastName, CardNumber
  FROM dbo.Users
  ORDER BY FirstName DESC
ELSE IF @filtername == "FirstName" && @filterorder == "ASC"
  SELECT UserId, FirstName, LastName, CardNumber
  FROM dbo.Users
  ORDER BY FirstName ASC
```

If the data gathering portion is more complicated then try using a temporary table to gather the data then do the above...

If you can leave out the filterorder piece of it... you can actually do this...

```
declare @filtername varchar(100) = 'FirstName'

select <columnlist> from dbo.Users
order by case when @filtername = 'FirstName' then FirstName end DESC
```

So, use the bottom method to figure out which column you want to filter on ... then use the top method (if/else) to determine ASC/DESC. Hope that helps.

Comment: the performance of your second solution (case construct) is far below acceptable in my experience, the execution plan can turn out really bad. Just stick with the first suggestion....

Comment: @Paul, I agree with you wholeheartedly.