# How to select datarow from datatable

Tags: vb.net, dataview

I get a data from textfile and use `dataset.tables(0)` and select columns by dataview. But I want to know how can I select or sorting rows data by (`column2 - data&time`). In short, I want see selected rows by `column2`

Can you give me a tips or example?

If The datatable is like this.

I want selected column2's 201405310010 and 201405310310 when I select datarows.

from

```
column2      | column3 | column4

**201405310010 | 2.155   | 22.90**

201405310030 | 2.156   | 22.90

201405310050 | 2.152   | 22.90

201405310110 | 2.151   | 22.90

201405310130 | 2.175   | 22.90

201405310150 | 2.155   | 22.90

201405310210 | 2.115   | 22.90

201405310240 | 2.165   | 22.90

**201405310310 | 2.255   | 22.90**
```

**Code**

to

column2      | column3 | column4

201405310010 | 2.155   | 22.90

201405310310 | 2.255   | 22.90

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To cols.Length Step 1
            ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add() 
        Next

        Dim row As String = sr.ReadLine()

        While row IsNot Nothing ' != null
            Dim rvalues As String() = RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(row, "/")

            ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(rvalues)
            row = sr.ReadLine() 'row 

        End While

        Dim diplayview = New DataView(ds.Tables(0))
        Dim subset As DataTable = diplayview.ToTable(False, "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column19", "column20") 'select columns

        GridView1.DataSource = subset
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Data Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472913/sorting-a-data-table)

Comment: use subset.Select("1=1", "column2 ASC") to get datarows in sorted order.

Comment: ... or `subset.DefaultView.Sort = "column2"`. for descending order `subset.DefaultView.Sort = "column2 DESC"`

Comment: Hello nelek thanks for your comment but My explanation is lacked. um...I want selected row. not sorting. :) do you know this way? sorry again for my lack of explanation.