# How to know what my next Short Code should be in a database

Tags: vb.net

I have a database that is sorted by a long code for example Y1D3D74945 then the short Code L1000 etc. They both need to be unique cant be duplicated at all but because its sorted by the long code I am not sure how to find what my next number for short code would be L2367 is the next empty number. This is what I have

```
Private Sub CmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
 CmdSearch.Click
         Dim SC As String,
             SCNew As String,
             LCNew As String,
             LC As String,
             Similiar As String,
             NotFound As Boolean,
             SCNum As Integer
 
         NotFound = True
         PartPos = 0
         TxtShortCode.Text = ""
         LCNew = Trim(TxtLongCode.Text)
         Similiar = LCNew.Substring(0, 13)
         For Each Row As DataRow In RatesDataSet.Codes.Rows
             LC = Trim(Row("Long Code"))
             SC = Trim(Row("Short Code"))
             If LC = TxtLongCode.Text Then
                 TxtShortCode.Text = Trim(Row("Short Code"))
                 NotFound = False
                 GoTo FinishLoop
             ElseIf LC.substring(0, 8) = "0 To Use" Then
                 TxtShortCode.Text = Trim(Row("Short Code"))
                 MsgBox("Update this Part Number", vbOKOnly)
                 'To get the row number to copy over
                 PartPos = Me.CodesBindingSource.Position
                 NotFound = False
                 GoTo FinishLoop
            ElseIf LCNew.Substring(0, 1) = LC.Substring(0, 1) Then
                 SCNum = SC.Substring(1, 4)
                 If LC.Substring(0, 13) = Similiar Then
                     TxtSimiliar.Text = SC
                ElseIf LC = LCNew Then
                     NotFound = False
                     TxtShortCode.Text = SC
                     GoTo FinishLoop
                 End If
             ElseIf SC = "Z9999" Then
                 SCNum = SCNum + 1
                 SCNew = LCNew.Substring(0, 1) & SCNum
                 TxtShortCode.Text = SCNew
                 MsgBox("This is a new item please add", vbOKOnly)
                 CmdAdd.Enabled = True
                 Me.AcceptButton = CmdAdd
             End If
         Next
         'if Not found
         If NotFound = False Then
             For Each Row As DataRow In RatesDataSet.Codes.Rows
                 SC = Trim(Row("Short Code"))
                 If SC.Substring(0, 1) = LCNew.Substring(0, 1) Then
                     'need to put the list in order by short code then add here what the next number would be
                 End If
 
             Next
         End If FinishLoop:
```

Comment: *I am not sure how to find what my next number* - next short number or long number?

Comment: the short number, so lets say as it would go down the rows on my database the last number is L2677 so the next empty one would be L2678.

Comment: Why not set the order to ShortCode, calculate your next code, then reset the order?  Although I suspect you could do this using a linq expression to calculate the Max ShortCode

Comment: how do I change what column to sort by just for this part then change it back?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472913/sorting-a-data-table/12473093

Comment: Is this a multi-user database?

Comment: no its not a multi user database